# tkinter : How to diplay an arbitary size dictionary in a canvas using lable and entry and manipulate the dictionary from entery input

Tags: tkinter

I wrote this code below where I have two buttons in the "componWin" canvas; when a user clicks them, each will pass a dictionary with different sizes and keys to be displayed in the "prpertyWin" canvas and in that canvas I want to create a grid of the same size of the passed dictionary and bind a data entry to each key to update the value of each corresponding components of the dictionary.
There is a global variable called "inputData" which will keep track of the state of both dictionaries of button1 and button2 and when user clickes the "print" key, it will print the latest update of the "inputData".
If you run the code, all will be more clear "I hope"!!
the problem is that I can't clear the "prpertyWin" when one of the buttons gets clicked, before dispaying it's dictionary and you can see in the background the older displayed widgets.

```
import tkinter
from functools import partial


def onCanvasConfigure(e):
    displayWin.itemconfig('frame', height=displayWin.winfo_height(), width=displayWin.winfo_width())

def but1Clicked():
    List1 = {'title':"but1 list", 'prop': {'Efficiency': 0.99, 'Input power': 10}}
    displayProp(List1)
def but2Clicked():
    List2 = {'title':"but2 list", 'prop': {'mdot 1': 0, 'T 1':273.15, 'mdot 2': 0, 'T 2':273.15}}
    displayProp(List2)

def printClicked():
    print("*****************************************************")
    print("but1 list = ", inputData["but1 list"])
    print("but2 list = ", inputData["but2 list"])
    print("*****************************************************")


mainWindow = tkinter.Toplevel()
mainWindow.title("Heat Exchanger")
sc_w = mainWindow.winfo_screenwidth()
sc_h = mainWindow.winfo_screenheight()
sc_size = str(sc_w)+"x"+str(sc_h)
mainWindow.geometry(sc_size)



componWin = tkinter.Canvas(mainWindow, bd=1, relief="sunken")
displayWin = tkinter.Canvas(mainWindow, bd=1, relief="sunken")
prpertyWin = tkinter.Canvas(mainWindow, bd=1, relief="sunken")

componWin.place(relx=0, relheight=1, relwidth=0.2)
prpertyWin.place(relx=0.8, relheight=1, relwidth=0.2)
displayWin.place(relx=0.2, relheight=1, relwidth=0.6)

inputData={"but1 list":{ 'prop': {'Efficiency': 0, 'Input power': 0}},
           "but2 list":{ 'prop': {'mdot 1': 0, 'T 1':0, 'mdot 2': 0, 'T 2':0}}}

pumpBtn = tkinter.Button(componWin, text="but1", command = but1Clicked).grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=(5,2.5), pady=(2.5, 2.5))
HxCounterBtn = tkinter.Button(componWin, text="but2", command = but2Clicked).grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx=(5,2.5), pady=(2.5, 2.5))
dataPrintBtn = tkinter.Button(componWin, text="Print", command = printClicked).grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx=(5,2.5), pady=(2.5, 2.5))



entries = []

def key_press(ix, key, title, event):
        inputData[title]['prop'][key] = entries[ix].get() + event.char


def displayProp(theList):
    header = tkinter.StringVar()
    header.set(theList['title'])
    headerPosition = tkinter.Label(prpertyWin, textvariable=header)
    headerPosition.grid_forget()
    headerPosition.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky="ew", padx = 5, pady = 5)
    i = 0
    for key, value in theList['prop'].items():
        tkinter.Label(prpertyWin, text=key, anchor="w").grid(row=i+1, column=0, sticky='ew', padx=5, pady=5)
        entries.append(tkinter.Entry(prpertyWin, bg='white'))
        entries[i].insert(tkinter.END, "")
        entries[i].grid(row=i+1, column=1, sticky="ew")
        entries[i].bind('<Key>', partial(key_press, i, key, theList['title']))
        i = i + 1


mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Any solution? Thanks very much in advance for your time.

Comment: No comments? is my question clear?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the right side canvas isn't being cleared properly when loading a new dictionary. First problem was that there wasn't any code to clear the canvas before creating the new widgets. This can be fixed by using the method `winfo_children()` to loop through all the widgets in the canvas, and using their destroy() method to get rid of them.

But even when this code is added, the problem persisted. The second problem is that the entries list wasn't being reset to an empty list, so when switching to a shorter dictionary it was overwriting the first list entries, but the old Entry widgets were being kept and being added back to the canvas using the grid geometry manager. Moving the `entries = []` line into the displayProp function solved this problem. Here's displayProp with the code changes.

```
def displayProp(theList):
    for widget in prpertyWin.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    entries = []
    header = tkinter.StringVar()
    header.set(theList['title'])
    headerPosition = tkinter.Label(prpertyWin, textvariable=header)
    headerPosition.grid_forget()
    headerPosition.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky="ew", padx = 5, pady = 5)
    i = 0
    for key, value in theList['prop'].items():
        tkinter.Label(prpertyWin, text=key, anchor="w").grid(row=i+1, column=0, sticky='ew', padx=5, pady=5)
        entries.append(tkinter.Entry(prpertyWin, bg='white'))
        entries[i].insert(tkinter.END, "")
        entries[i].grid(row=i+1, column=1, sticky="ew")
        entries[i].bind('<Key>', partial(key_press, i, key, theList['title']))
        i = i + 1
```

Not sure why this went unanswered for so long! Hope it's not too late to help!

Comment: Dear schwartz721; 
Thank you so much for your time and detail answer, but the problem is still there, because as I mentioned, I need to keep tracking the latest inserted value, but in your answer, you clear each time the "entries " when displayProp function is called.
I need to see the last value entered in entries of button 1 when I go to button 2 and come back to button 1.